# PHP Slim exclude path to a directory

Tags: php, slim

I have created API using PHP Slim. I have a directory with images and... when I want to use (e.g.) '.../images/index.jpg' I see 404 because Slim is looking for a path to a controller. Do you know how to exclude this direcatory?

**EDIT**

This is my Routes.php

```
declare(strict_types=1);

use Slim\App;

return function (App $app) {
    //about me
    $app->get('/aboutme', [\App\Actions\AboutMeAction::class, "getAll"])->setName('aboutme_get');
    $app->patch('/aboutme', [\App\Actions\AboutMeAction::class, "change"])->setName('aboutme_update');

    //photos
    $app->get('/photos', [\App\Actions\PhotoAction::class, "getAll"])->setName('photo_get_all');
    $app->post('/photos', [\App\Actions\PhotoAction::class, "addNew"])->setName('photo_add_new');
    $app->delete('/photos/{name}', [\App\Actions\PhotoAction::class, "delete"])->setName('photo_delete');
    $app->patch('/photos/{name}', [\App\Actions\PhotoAction::class, "changeFlag"])->setName('photo_change_flag');
    $app->get('/photos/download', [\App\Actions\PhotoAction::class, "download"])->setName('photo_download');

    //users
    $app->post('/login', [\App\Actions\UserAction::class, "signIn"])->setName('login');

    //utils
    $app->get('/utils', [\App\Actions\UtilsAction::class, "test"])->setName("tests");
};
```

my project's structure (only part):

```
├─ config/
│  ├─ bootstrap.php
│  ├─ container.php
│  ├─ middleware.php
│  ├─ routes.php
│  ├─ settings.php
├─ images/
├─ logs/
├─ public/
│  ├─ index.php
├─ src/
│  ├─ Actions/
│  ├─ Domain/
│  │  ├─ Repositories/
│  │  │  ├─ StorageRepository.php
│  │  ├─ Services/
├─ tests/
```

Sooo... when I want to get image, this path [example](http://localhost:8080/images/example.jpg) should works... I quess.
Where is the problem?

I use InfiniteFree

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This shouldn't happen. I think you haven't configured your web server (Nginx, Apache, IIS...) correctly. Can you please edit the question and add more information about that?

Comment: What is your web server software? What configurations have you set to instruct it to invoke `public/index.php` for requests?

Comment: I used this tutorial https://odan.github.io/2019/11/05/slim4-tutorial.html

Comment: Please double-check that both `.htaccess` files are identical to what article says. A request for an **existing** picture will not comply with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` so `RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]` won't trigger and `index.php` will not be invoked.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: What do you need help with? I don't think this is a PHP or Slim problem at all, as you're seemingly assuming. I guess you could implement a PHP workaround for incorrect web server settings but why would you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want Apache to invoke your `public/index.php` script for static assets. The [tutorial you followed](https://odan.github.io/2019/11/05/slim4-tutorial.html) seems to have that covered, so perhaps you omitted some steps or have a copy+paste typo:

```
# Redirect to front controller
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /

# Apply rule only if the request does not match a directory on disk:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# ... and the request does not match a file on disk:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# All good? Then apply the redirection rule:
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I personally find mod_rewrite very counter-intuitive and prefer to avoid if when it isn't necessary. You can try the [`FallbackResource` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) instead (IMHO, less chances for something to be wrong):

```
FallbackResource index.php
```

Comment: thank you. I have an access to an image now, but when I do this: ".../api/photos" I am redirect to 404